# Custom DependencyProperty in style triggers using TemplateBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm having an issue getting the following to work. I have created a subclass of button with several DependencyProperties. and we are attempting to use these in the style.

We have the following c#

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  Custom Is Mouse Over Colour.
    /// </summary>
    public static DependencyProperty LITIsMouseOverProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LITIsMouseOver",
        typeof(System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush), typeof(Button));

    public static System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush GetLITIsMouseOver(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return (System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush)target.GetValue(LITIsMouseOverProperty);
    }

    public static void SetLITIsMouseOver(DependencyObject target, System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush value)

    {
        target.SetValue(LITIsMouseOverProperty, value);
    }
```

and the following XAML:

```
    <Style x:Key="StandardButton" TargetType="{x:Type Utils:LITCustomButton01}">
     <Setter Property="LITIsMouseOver" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Utils:LITCustomButton01}">
                    <Border x:Name="buttonBorder"  CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding LITCornerRadius}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Name="textBlock" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                    </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding LITIsMouseOver}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>  
     </Style>
```

We have this same system working on corner radius, using the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  Custom Corner Radius
    /// </summary>
    public static DependencyProperty LITCornerRadiusProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LITCornerRadius",
        typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(Button));

    public static CornerRadius GetLITCornerRadius(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return (CornerRadius)target.GetValue(LITCornerRadiusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetLITCornerRadius(DependencyObject target, CornerRadius value)
    {
        target.SetValue(LITCornerRadiusProperty, value);
    }
```

However, the background throws the following error:

"member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name."

Comment: your posting about the error is missing.

Comment: AH damn, thanks for pointing that out, had a couple of issues with posting.

Answer (score 1):

`TemplateBinding` can only be used in a `ControlTemplate`. The `TemplateBinding` shortcut does not work in triggers so you will have to use the `RelativeSource` binding.  When overriding the `ControlTemplate` you will need to specify the target of the trigger.  Something like this:

```
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
               Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Background"
                   TargetName="buttonBorder"
                   Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LITIsMouseOver}"/>
      </Trigger>
 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Also, you are creating an attached property which would allow you to do:

```
 <Grid Utils:LITCustomButton01.LITIsMouseOver="Pink"/>
```

In this case, nothing will happen on `MouseOver`.  You want to use `Register` as opposed to `RegisterAttached`.